# How to set my own DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm not sure this is a right site for this kind of a question but I decided to give it a try...

Well, I have a new server running on its own IP address with Plesk installed. Plesk provides me a primary DNS server and I would like to set my primary domain (lets say domain.com) as a nameserver, I understand I have to do this in registrant's DNS settings and my question is how can I do this.

Can I simply create an A record with ns.domain.com pointing to my server's IP and then link all my remaining domains to that (ns.domain.com) or is there also something else? The thing is, I'd like to skip registrant's DNS a configure DNS records right in my Plesk panel (for other than primary domains of course).

I'd also like to ask if you'd recommend any other free DNS services which allow me to create secondary, tertiary,... nameservers.

Thanks a lot for you replies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to buy your domain. Then, the registrar will (must) give you access to the configuration panel where you can either list your host (A Records), or specify a NameServer (NS record) responsible for the domain.
In this second case, which is what you want to do, the registrar will simply delegate all request concerning your domain to the nameserver you've specificied.

So, in the registrar configuration, if you want the host 'ns.mydomain.com' to be in charge of 'mydomain.com', you need the following two records:

```
     IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.
ns0  IN      A       <ip address>
```

This is the configuration for Bind. Most registrar offer you a configuration panel that's a bit more friendly... or not. In any case, look for the 'DNS server for the zone' page of your registrar.

Comment: Firstly, in the example above it should ns IN A (not ns0). Secondly, if you run your own DNS server, the registrar has to register that name server with the relevant authority for the TLD, so that the root servers can be primed with that knowledge. This is more often than not a separate procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the weird thing (and the reason I didn't figured it out) was that my current registrar doesn't support creating/editing "NS" dns entries, I switched to another and everything is fine, I used settings you suggested and it looks like it's working. Thanks a lot!